# Передача ссылки на константный указатель в функцию

Tags: c++

Хотел передать ссылку на указатель так, чтобы он не мог менять значение, на которое указывает, но выдает ошибку:

```
#include <iostream>

void qwer(const int *&z)
{
        std::cout << *z << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
        int a = 11;
        int *x = &a;

        qwer(x);
        return 0;
}
```

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:14:7: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘const int*&’ to an rvalue of type ‘const int*’
   14 |  qwer(x);
      |       ^
main.cpp:4:23: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void qwer(const int*&)’
    4 | void qwer(const int *&z)
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Также не понятно, как сделать константной именно ссылку, а не указатель.

Comment: Вам нужна константная ссылка на указатель на `int`, или ссылка на указатель на константный `int`, или ссылка на константный указатель на `int`? :) По условию непонятно, устроит ли вас, например, `void qwer(int * const &z)`?

Comment: @Harry хах. Расскажите как делать всё, если не трудно))

Comment: `const int * cx{x}; qwer(cx);`

Comment: @user7860670 а почему без `const` не работает?

Comment: Потому что функция принимает ссылку на объект с типом "указатель на неизменяемый `int`", а в примере таких объектов нет, а попытка передать временный объект этого типа созданный из `x` не работает, так как ссылка на изменяемый объект не может ссылаться на временный объект.

Comment: Зачем вам вообще подобные "изыски"? Если в функции используется *число*, так и передавайте туда *его*. Если собираетесь изменять там значение *переменной*, то передавайте в функцию *указатель*. Все остальное это следствие попыток средствами языка исправить ошибки программиста, который сам не понимает что творит. Вы же не собираетесь быть *таким программистом*?

Comment: Ну, показываю несколько вариантов, если хотите...

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам немножко вариантов попроще... Некомпилируемое закомментировано.

```
using cint  = const int;
using pint  = int *;
using cpint = cint *;

void f1(pint & x)       // Ссылка на указатель на int
{
    *x = 3;
    x = nullptr;
}

void f2(cpint & x)      // Ссылка на указатель на константный int
{
    //*x = 3;
    x = nullptr;
}
void f3(pint const & x) // Cсылка на константный указатель на int
{
    *x = 3;
    //x = nullptr;
}
void f4(cpint const & x)// Ссылка на константный указатель на константный int
{
    //*x = 3;
    //x = nullptr;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int a = 5;
    int * p = &a;
    const int b = 6;
    const int * q = &b;
    f1(p);
    f2(q);
    f3(p);
    f4(p);

    f3(nullptr);
    f4(nullptr);

}
```

Кстати, покрутите разные определения [тут](https://cdecl.org/), например, `const int * const & const p` :)

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае если было-бы возможно передавать ссылку `const int *` на `int *`, то функция могла-бы менять указатель на константный объект.

```
int const ci = 7 ;
void qwer(const int * & z) {
  z = & ci ; }

int main()
{
    int a = 11;
    int *x = &a;

    qwer((const int *&)x);
    * x = 9 ; }
```

а функция `main` могла-бы модифицировать константный объект, что привело-бы к дырке безопасности или произойти неопределённое поведение.

```
$ ./constarg 
Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)
```

Разрешается три варианта :

1. всё не константа

   ```
   void qwer(int *&z)
   ..
   int *x = &a;
   ```
2. аргумент : и объект и указатель константа

   ```
   void qwer(int const * const & z)
   ..
   int *x = &a;
   ```
3. указатель только на константный объект

   ```
   void qwer(int const * & z)
   ..
   int const *x = &a;
   ```

*Ссылка всегда константная*

---

перевод https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion

### Почему я получаю ошибку преобразования Foo** → const Foo**?

Потому что преобразование Foo** → const Foo** было бы недопустимым и опасным.

C++ допускает (безопасное) преобразование Foo* → Foo const*, но выдает ошибку, если вы пытаетесь неявно преобразовать Foo** → const Foo**.

Обоснование того, почему эта ошибка является хорошей вещью, приведено ниже. Но сначала вот самое распространенное решение: просто измените `const Foo**` на `const Foo* const*`:

```
class Foo { /* ... */ };
void f(const Foo** p);
void g(const Foo* const* p);
int main()
{
  Foo** p = /*...*/;
  // ...
  f(p);  // ОШИБКА: преобразование Foo** в const Foo незаконно и аморально**
  g(p);  // Хорошо: законно и морально преобразовывать Foo** в const Foo* const*
  // ...
}
```

Причина, по которой преобразование из Foo** → const Foo** опасно, заключается в том, что оно позволит вам молча и случайно изменить объект const Foo без приведения:

```
class Foo {
public:
  void modify();  // внесите некоторые изменения в этот объект
};
int main()
{
  const Foo x;
  Foo* p;
  const Foo** q = &p;  // q теперь указывает на p; это (к счастью!) ошибка
  *q = &x;             // теперь p указывает на x
  p->modify();         // Ой: изменяет константу Foo!!
  // ...
}
```

Если бы строка `q = &p` была законной, q указывала бы на p. Следующая строка, `*q = &x`, изменяет сам p (так как `*q`-это `p`), чтобы указать на x. Это было бы плохо, так как мы потеряли бы квалификатор const: p-это Foo*, но x-это const Foo. Строка `p->modify()` использует способность p изменять свою ссылку, что является реальной проблемой, поскольку мы в конечном итоге изменили const Foo.

По аналогии, если вы прячете преступника под законной личиной, он может воспользоваться доверием, оказанным этой личине. Это плохо.

К счастью, C++ не позволяет вам этого сделать: строка `q = &p` помечается компилятором C++ как ошибка времени компиляции. Напоминание: пожалуйста, не делайте преобразование типа чтобы обойти это сообщения об ошибке во время компиляции. Просто Скажи "Нет"!

*(Примечание: существует концептуальное сходство между этим и  [запретом на преобразование `Derived**` в `Base**`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/proper-inheritance#derivedptrptr-to-baseptrptr).)*